# after a date is sent to db, it is saved the previous date

Tags: angular, datetime

I am sending a date via Angular to my mongoDb collection.

this is what I'm sending 
[image]

and this is what I recieve
[image]

I'm thinking that the problem here is about UTC dates, and that's why I tried to convert my date to UTC; also I have tried to set the hours, minutes and seconds to 0 but it's not working.

How to send this date corectly?

```
this.holidayClicked = function (day: CalendarMonthViewDay): Observable<boolean> {
        const username = 'dinchmle';
        const holiday = new EmployeeHoliday();
        // transform date in UTC date
        holiday.date = day.date;
        holiday.date.setHours(0, 0, 0);
        holiday.date.setUTCDate(day.date.getUTCDate());
        holiday.date.setUTCMonth(day.date.getUTCMonth());
        holiday.date.setUTCFullYear(day.date.getUTCFullYear());
        holiday.state = that.stateSelected;
        holiday.comment = '';

        return that.calendarService.updateEmployee(username, holiday).map(
          response => {
            if (holiday && holiday.state !== 1) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          });
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify, I'm not sure what language that is in your back-end snippet, but it looks like C# ?

Anyway, you are sending the date with a timezone - GMT+0200 
This is a correct way to send it, and contains all of the information that the back-end needs to properly save the date.

On the back-end, you are transforming the received date with DateTime.SpecifyKind, which from a quick web search (I don't know C#), looks like it overrides the timezone, in your case to ignore the Date's timezone and force it to UTC.

This would have the effect of moving the time by the amount of your original Date's timezone offset from UTC (2 hours), resulting in 10pm on the previous day instead of.midnight on the intended day.

So, use the Date's actual timezone instead of overriding it to UTC.